# Data discretization in db in an intelligent way

Tags: sql, database, loops, rabbitmq, clickhouse

For my futur project i have a ClickHouse db. This db is fed by several micro-services themselves fed by rabbitsMQ.

The data look like:

```
| Datetime            | nodekey | value |
| 2018-01-01 00:10:00 |      15 |   156 |
| 2018-01-01 00:10:00 |      18 |   856 |
| 2018-01-01 00:10:00 |      86 |     8 |
| 2018-01-01 00:20:00 |      15 |   156 |
| 2018-01-01 00:20:00 |      18 |    84 |
| 2018-01-01 00:20:00 |      86 |    50 |
 ......
```

So for hundreds different nodekey, I have a value every 10 minutes.

I need to have another table with the sum or the means (depends on nodekey type) of the values for every hours ...

My first idea is just using a crontab ...
But the data didn't comming in fluid flow, sometime micro-service add 2 - 3 new values or some time a weeks of data comming ... and rarely i have to bulk insert a years of the new data...

And for the moment i only have hundreds nodekey but the project going to grows.

So, i think using a crontab or looping throught the db for updating data isn't a good idea...

What is my other options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just creating a view?

```
create view myview as
select 
    toStartOfHour(datetime) date_hour,
    nodekey,
    sum(value) sum_value
from mytable
group by 
    toStartOfHour(datetime),
    nodekey
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to worry about refreshing the data. When querying the view, you actually access the underlying live data. The downside is that it might not scale well when your dataset becomes really big (queries adressing the view will tend to slow down).

An intermediate option would be to use a [materialized view](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/create/), that will persist the data. If I correctly understand the clickhouse documentation, materialized views are automatically updated when the data in the source table is modified, which seems to be close to what you are looking for (however you need to use the proper engine, and this might impact the performance of your inserts).

Comment: In fact hours is the first step, i to discretize y days, slipery weeks, month ect ...
In total maybe 30 table like that ...

I like the views approach but i'm affrayde about performance about views of views ...

Comment: @Andrelec1: just create one view for each level of aggregation. You can just change `toStartOfHour()` to `toStartOfDay()`, `toStartOfWeek()`, and so on.